# Pointing to specific line in program with if statement? Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a program which asks the user to input a value between 1 and 6. However, if they don't ask between that range, I would like the program to ask the user to input again. I have other code within the method, so I can't just point to the method.

```
System.out.print("Now enter a number between 1 and 6 ");
        dieNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (dieNumber == 1){        
            drawOne(pane);  }   
        else if (dieNumber == 2){
            drawTwo(pane);  }
        else if (dieNumber == 3){
            drawThree(pane);}
        else if (dieNumber == 4){
            drawFour(pane); }
        else if (dieNumber == 5){
            drawFive(pane); }
        else if (dieNumber == 6){
            drawSix(pane); }
```

Comment: Did you try enclosing the code snippet with a `while` loop? Seems like it should work to me.

Comment: @Keppil Yes, but at the end of the day I still need something that says, if it's not in between that range, run it again.

Comment: And that's what the `while` loop is for

Comment: @AntonH Yup, I was thinking of it the wrong way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to make while loop to ask again every time the user inputted a number greater than 6

```js
System.out.print("Now enter a number between 1 and 6 ");
  
  dieNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
  while (dieNumber > 6){
   System.out.print("Now enter a number between 1 and 6 ");
   dieNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
  }
  if (dieNumber == 1){  
   drawOne(pane); } 
  else if (dieNumber == 2){
   drawTwo(pane); }
  else if (dieNumber == 3){
   drawThree(pane); }
  else if (dieNumber == 4){
   drawFour(pane); }
  else if (dieNumber == 5){
   drawFive(pane); }
  else if (dieNumber == 6){
   drawSix(pane); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which doesn't require adding a `break;` or any other repeated code to every path:

```
boolean needToTryAgain;
do {
    needToTryAgain = false;
    System.out.print("Now enter a number between 1 and 6 ");
    dieNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (dieNumber == 1){        
        drawOne(pane);  }   
    else if (dieNumber == 2){
        drawTwo(pane);  }
    else if (dieNumber == 3){
        drawThree(pane);}
    else if (dieNumber == 4){
        drawFour(pane); }
    else if (dieNumber == 5){
        drawFive(pane); }
    else if (dieNumber == 6){
        drawSix(pane); }
    else {
        // this would be a good place to print an error message
        needToTryAgain = true;
    }
} while (needToTryAgain);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add a `while` and `break;` if select numbers that you want, the `break` will break the while loop other than that, it will ask user to enter another number.

```
while(true){
    System.out.print("Now enter a number between 1 and 6 ");
    dieNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (dieNumber == 1){        
        drawOne(pane);  break;}   
    else if (dieNumber == 2){
        drawTwo(pane);  break;}
    else if (dieNumber == 3){
        drawThree(pane);break;}
    else if (dieNumber == 4){
        drawFour(pane); break;}
    else if (dieNumber == 5){
        drawFive(pane); break;}
    else if (dieNumber == 6){
        drawSix(pane);  break;}
}
```